# How to detect when an OAuth2 refresh-token expired

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, onedrive, refresh-token

When accessing Google-Drive, an access-token can expire and we can use the refresh-token to get a new access-token. There are a number of possible reasons though, that the refresh-token itself stops working or expires, see:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration

So my question, what happens if the refresh-token has expired after the 6 months, how can I detect it? Does the request for refreshing the access-token fail with *403 forbidden*, or does it return a JSON containing an error message, or something else?

Unfortunately it is hard to find any information about this, and to test it out one has to wait for 6 month...

**Solution:**

Thanks to Gary Archers answer I could produce the situation with an invalid refresh-token and this is the response I got, maybe it helps somebody else:

```
HTTP-status-code: 400
JSON:
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for directly retrieving the expiration time of the refresh token. So as the current workarounds, I'm using the following methods. 1. When the refresh token is retrieved, it retrieves the retrieved time. 2. When the access token is retrieved with the refresh token, confirms the error. This has already been mentioned by your question. If these were not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike - I already suspected, that there is no "official" way to find it out, I just hoped that somebody encountered this situation and could tell how the server responds when I try to refresh the access-token with an expired refresh-token.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my proposal was not useful for your situation.

Comment: Thank you for the replying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost all implementations I've seen return a known error code of 'invalid_grant' that you can check for. It will look something like this, with the server returning a JSON response with an `error` field and an optional `error_description`. At this point you need to redirect the user to reauthenticate:

[image]